# Java - Como validar grupo do usuário no SQL e Salvar resultado?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, window-builder

Bom dia,

Estou com seguinte código em Java Desktop.
Queria saber como posso capturar o grupo desse usuário e salvar em uma variável. Já que quando ele retorna o valor e armazena na variável "rs" não contém uma informação compreendida para o desenvolvedor. Precisa do nome do grupo do usuário para abrir um jFrame de acordo com o grupo dele.

```
public class UsuarioD {

public static Boolean doLogin(model.UsuarioM usuario) {

    // Variáveis
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String sql = "select * from usuario where nome=? and senha=?";

    try {

        // Validar
        ps = ConectarDB.getConexao().prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, usuario.getNome());
        ps.setString(2, usuario.getSenha());
        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        // Validar
        if(rs.next()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }            

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Isso vai depender também de como você armazena os grupos. É um campo String na tabela ``usuario`` ou em uma tabela diferente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma das alternativas para resolver esse problema é a seguinte: ao invés de retornar true ou false, retornar um objeto do tipo Usuario caso o login tenha sucesso. Assim, você pode popular esse objeto usuário com todas as informações necessárias.

Note que se o login não obtiver sucesso devido ao usuario e senha passados como parametro, então uma exceção é levantada.

Veja abaixo:

```
public static Usuario doLogin(String usuario, String senha) throws SQLException {
    // Variáveis
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String sql = "select * from usuario where nome=? and senha=?";
    Usuario usuario = new Usuario();

    // Validar
    ps = ConectarDB.getConexao().prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.setString(1, usuario);
    ps.setString(2, senha);
    rs = ps.executeQuery();

    // Validar
    if(rs.next()) {
        usuario.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
        usuario.setGrupo(rs.getString("grupo"));    
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Usuario ou senha incorretos, favor verificar.");
    }            

    return usuario;
}
```

Comment: Excelente! Muito obrigado !!